# Where is the java.exe that launched me?

Tags: java

Is there some way I can find the path to the java.exe that launched me?

In this case I am on Windows but if there is a general solution I would welcome it.

**Added**

FYI: In most cases my tool will be launched from a full path to an unregistered java.exe. e.g. `C:\ABC\DEF\SDK\JRE\BIN\Java -jar MyTool.jar`. Can I find the `C:\ABC\DEF\SDK\JRE\BIN\`.

Yes it is rather self-referential. :)

Comment: You could install the fabulous Cygwin and type 'which java'. Other than that I believe it's a matter of manually following each directory in your path until you find it.

Comment: This is a first, an A.I. looking for info on it's parent. :)

Comment: What is your PATH set to? For Windows, open a DOS window and type `set path` to view the path which should include one or more Java _bin_ directories on it (where `java.exe` lives)

Comment: Question edited to clarify. @Kevin: Yes it is rather incestuous. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, there is no need for java.exe to launch java code. But you might want to look into the `java.home` system property

Comment: Strangely when I use `C:\XX\YY\SDK\JRE\BIN\Java -jar ...` I get `java.home=C:\XX\YY\SDK\JRE` but it does consistently give me the folder containing the jre so good answer! Also, when launched without a full path I correctly get `java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6` which works for me.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `java.home` system property. I am sure that cases can be contrived where you start with `JAVA_HOME` set to a different directory from the one that contains your `java.exe`, but I this should be good enough for standard cases.

```
scala> System.getProperty("java.home")
res3: java.lang.String = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\jre
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows when you execute java.exe from command line or from native OS it will look for all the dir listen in env variable PATH + the current directory. Hope that helps